# How do i configure preview endpoint in dreamweaver?

Tags: dreamweaver

If i use a live preview of dreamweaver, it will spawn a server, for example at:

http://127.0.0.1:50852/preview/app/index.html

The problem here is, i dont want to have the **/preview/app** and i want to right away using index in path so i will see that i will use this path as preview:

http://127.0.0.1:50852/index.html

And how to configure the port to not using the port it created?